Error compile TypeScript: error TS5024: Compiler option 'target' requires a value of type string
I'm setting up an environment to work on a WSL. I want to work with typescript files but I have issue executing script in my project.
If I execute the following command ts-node -e 'console.log("hello")' outside of my project directory it works but if I go into my project and I execute the same command I get the following error:
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript: error TS5024: Compiler option 'target' requires a value of type string.
Here is my package.json file:
{
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "lint:fix": "prettier */*.js \"*/**/*{.js,.ts}\" -w",
    "lint": "prettier */*.js \"*/**/*{.js,.ts}\" --check"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@coral-xyz/anchor": "^0.30.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bn.js": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/chai": "^4.3.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^20.14.8",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "mocha": "^9.0.3",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "ts-mocha": "^10.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "tslib": "^2.6.3",
    "typescript": "^5.5.2"
  }
}

Here is my tsconfig.json file:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["mocha", "chai", "node"],
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": ["es6"],
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}

Kinda new to typescript and environment setup tbh but I followed online installation guide.
My version of node is 20.15.0 which I installed executing the nvm command.
EDIT: I also executed these commands:
# Locally in your project.
npm install -D typescript
npm install -D ts-node

# Or globally with TypeScript.
npm install -g typescript
npm install -g ts-node

# Depending on configuration, you may also need these
npm install -D tslib @types/node


You need to specify target as a string :
"target": "es6",


It worked, thanks can't believe it was just this.
